# I configured Configure SSL in apache, later installed mysql,php by followin steps in below link, after that when tried to open php it is getting error

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-16.04, devops, server-configuration

I configured Configure SSL in apache, later installed mysql,php by followin steps in below link, after that when tried to open php it is getting below error

link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-1-install-apache-and-allow-in-firewall

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Message /info.php
```

> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.15

Comment: Is your secure virtual-host pointing to the correct document root?

Comment: Also, why are you using [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) to server PHP files?